# How to set form input required attribute in laravel 4

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-4, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm using the laravel framework for a project, and I'm implementing a basic form page, where I require certain values to be `required`, something that can be done very easily in HTML5.

```
<input type="text" name="abc" required>
```

In laravel, without the `required` attribute, the same would be :

```
{{ Form::text('abc') }}
```

How do I incorporate a required attribute in the above statement?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since simply writing `['required']` did not work, I searched online a bit more and found the answer, so I thought I'd share it here.

The third parameter is an array of optional attributes, which, in convention, must be written as:

```
{{ Form::text('abc','',array('required' => 'required')) }}
```

Similarly, for a radio button with default selected/checked we have:

```
{{ Form::radio('abc', 'yes', array('checked' => 'checked')) }}
```

Comment: Why is `'required' => 'required'` needed?

Will just `require` not work?

Comment: @darrenb  From an html perspective, "required" on its own is fine, but this function needs a key => value array pair to work

Comment: @JonRhoades If you check out Laravel's HtmlBuilder class, and specifically the attributeElement method, you will see that you are mistaken. If a key is numeric, the key will be set to the value. So ['required'] in effect is the same as ['required' => 'required'].

Answer (score 14):

Check out the [API-Docs](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html#235-246). The method signature shows that you can provide 3 parameters.

The first one is the **name** attribute, the second one is the **value** attribute. Third one is your array with any additional attributes.

So just call your method with:

```
{{ Form::text('key', 'value', ['required']) }}
```

And a `required` attribute will be attached to your input field.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the correct answer is similar to the other post where the third parameter is

```
array('required' => 'required')
```

however to get the attribute without any value you can do the following:

```
array('required' => '')
```

The input field (for text example), will then look what was necessary in the question.

Laravel Example:

```
{{ Form::text('title', '', array('tabindex' => '1', 'required' => '')) }}
```

HTML output:

```
<input tabindex="1" required name="title" type="text" value="" id="title">
```

I believe this actually shorthand for required='', just wanted to add this note

Comment: Excellent on L4.2

Comment: Just a note for anyone finding this and looking to add 'required' to a file input field - rather than the third parameter, for file inputs required should be the second parameter (in 5.4 at least, not tested in others).  So for a required file input you'd create your field as below

```{!! Form::file('thumbnail', ['required']) !!}```

Answer (score 2):

Radio required featured works with laravel 5.7 version

```
@foreach($status_list as $status_key => $status)
  {!! Form::radio('status', $status_key, false, array('id'=>'status_'.$status_key, 'required'=>'required' )); !!}
  {!! Form::label('status_'.$status_key, $status ) !!}
@endforeach
```

I hope, this will help you also. :)