# Laravel all input fields are required

Tags: validation, laravel

I have about 50 input fields and they are all required.
Is there a easy way to check if they are all set?
So i don't have to manually put every field in my model with a validation rule of "required"?

Comment: Have you tried anything? See if this applys/helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405524/how-to-set-form-input-required-attribute-in-laravel-4

Comment: Have you tried `protected $guarded = ['id'];`, it should white-list all the other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to avoid referencing each of your 50 fields inside your `rules()` method, as the returned array goes through this one :

```
/**
 * Explode the rules into an array of rules.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $rules
 * @return array
 */
protected function explodeRules($rules)
{
    foreach ($rules as $key => &$rule)
    {
        $rule = (is_string($rule)) ? explode('|', $rule) : $rule;
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

You can see it in the Validator's constructor here : https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/master/Validator.php

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late, but I wrote a simple function to solve this problem for myself

```
foreach ($request->except('_token') as $data => $value) {
  $valids[$data] = "required";
}

$request->validate($valids);
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks alot you do not  need if statement  just pass the $valids array to validator

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code below. This worked for me to make all request fields required.

```
$request->validate([
        '*' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($req->except('_token') as $data=>$value){
    $valids[$data] = "required";
 }

 $validator=  validator($req->all(),$valids);
 if ($validator->fails()) {
 foreach($validator->messages()->getMessages() as $key=>$val){
            $response["$key"]=$val;
        }
        return response()->json([
            'success'   => 0,
            'errors'    =>$response,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can use `validator` from `Facades` like this:

```
try {
    foreach ($request->except('_token') as $data => $value) {
        $valids[$data] = "required";
    }

    $validator = validator($request->all(), $valids);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        foreach ($validator->messages()->getMessages() as $key => $val) {
            $response["$key"] = $val;
        }
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($response)
            ->withInput();
    }
}catch(\Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage()) ;
}
```