# Laravel PHP form wont submit to database or recognise my Route in web.php (but works for my first form)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm kind of new to Laravel. I have 2 separate pages, one is a form for teachers and one is a form for parents. The parent form works completely fine and I can see the results in my database, however, my teacher form wont submit. The page refreshes and that's all. I noticed my Route for my teacher form wasn't being recognised when using Route:list in the terminal. I don't know how to get it to recognise my route for post. I've cleared routes and rewritten the route command but nothing is working, any suggestions would be great.

These are my Routes - originally teachers route had "post" and not "submit" - not sure that changes anything ...

```
Auth::routes();
Route::view('/checklist-teachers','teachers');
Route::post('submit', [App\Http\Controllers\TChecklistController::class, 'submitteacherform']);

Auth::routes();
Route::view('/checklist-parents', 'parents');
Route::post('submit', [App\Http\Controllers\TChecklistController::class, 'submitparentform']);
```

Controller functions

```
class TChecklistController extends Controller
{
    public function teachers()
    {
        return view("teachers");
    }

        public function submitteacherform(Request $request) {
            /*echo 'we are here';
            $this->validate($request, [
                "int1"=>"required",
                "int2"=>"required",
                "int3"=>"required",
                "int4"=>"required",
                "int5"=>"required",
                "int6"=>"required",
                "int7"=>"required",
                "int8"=>"required",
                "int9"=>"required",
                "int10"=>"required",
                "int11"=>"required",
                "cre12"=>"required",
                "cre13"=>"required",
                "cre14"=>"required",
                "cre15"=>"required",
                "cre16"=>"required",
                "cre17"=>"required",
                "cre18"=>"required",
                "soc19"=>"required",
                "soc20"=>"required",
                "soc21"=>"required",
                "soc22"=>"required",
                "per23"=>"required",
                "per24"=>"required",
                "per25"=>"required",
                "per26"=>"required",
                "per27"=>"required",
                "muc28"=>"required",
                "muc29"=>"required",
                "muc30"=>"required",
                "moc31"=>"required",
                "moc32"=>"required",
                "moc33"=>"required",
                "sp34"=>"required",
                "sp35"=>"required",
                "sp36"=>"required",
                "sp37"=>"required",
                "sp38"=>"required",
                "sp39"=>"required",
                "sp40"=>"required",
                ],[
                    "int1.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int2.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int3.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int4.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int5.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int6.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int7.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int8.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int9.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int10.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "int11.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "cre12.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "cre13.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "cre14.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "cre15.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "cre16.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "cre17.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "cre18.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "soc19.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "soc20.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "soc21.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "soc22.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "per23.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "per24.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "per25.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "per26.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "per27.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "muc28.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "muc29.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "muc30.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "moc31.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "moc32.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "moc33.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "sp34.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "sp35.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "sp36.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "sp37.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "sp38.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "sp39.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                    "sp40.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                ]);*/

                    //insert into database
                $user_id = Auth::user()->name;
                $int1 = $request->input('int1');
                $int2 = $request->input('int2');
                $int3 = $request->input('int3');
                $int4 = $request->input('int4');
                $int5 = $request->input('int5');
                $int6 = $request->input('int6');
                $int7 = $request->input('int7');
                $int8 = $request->input('int8');
                $int9 = $request->input('int9');
                $int10 = $request->input('int10');
                $int11 = $request->input('int11');
                $cre12 = $request->input('cre12');
                $cre13 = $request->input('cre13');
                $cre14 = $request->input('cre14');
                $cre15 = $request->input('cre15');
                $cre16 = $request->input('cre16');
                $cre17 = $request->input('cre17');
                $cre18 = $request->input('cre18');
                $soc19 = $request->input('soc19');
                $soc20 = $request->input('soc20');
                $soc21 = $request->input('soc21');
                $soc22 = $request->input('soc22');
                $per23 = $request->input('per23');
                $per24 = $request->input('per24');
                $per25 = $request->input('per25');
                $per26 = $request->input('per26');
                $per27 = $request->input('per27');
                $muc28 = $request->input('muc28');
                $muc29 = $request->input('muc29');
                $muc30 = $request->input('muc30');
                $moc31 = $request->input('moc31');
                $moc32 = $request->input('moc32');
                $moc33 = $request->input('moc33');
                $sp34 = $request->input('sp34');
                $sp35 = $request->input('sp35');
                $sp36 = $request->input('sp36');
                $sp37 = $request->input('sp37');
                $sp38 = $request->input('sp38');
                $sp39 = $request->input('sp39');
                $sp40 = $request->input('sp40');
                $data1=array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'int1'=>$int1, 'int2'=>$int2, 'int3'=>$int3, 'int4'=>$int4, 'int5'=>$int5, 'int6'=>$int6, 'int7'=>$int7, 'int8'=>$int8, 'int9'=>$int9, 'int10'=>$int10, 'int11'=>$int11, 'cre12'=>$cre12, 'cre13'=>$cre13, 'cre14'=>$cre14, 'cre15'=>$cre15, 'cre16'=>$cre16, 'cre17'=>$cre17,  'cre18'=>$cre18, 'soc19'=>$soc19, 'soc20'=>$soc20, 'soc21'=>$soc21, 'soc22'=>$soc22, 'per23'=>$per23, 'per24'=>$per24, 'per25'=>$per25, 'per26'=>$per26, 'per27'=>$per27, 'muc28'=>$muc28, 'muc29'=>$muc29, 'muc30'=>$muc30, 'moc31'=>$moc31, 'moc32'=>$moc32, 'moc33'=>$moc33, 'sp34'=>$sp34, 'sp35'=>$sp35, 'sp36'=>$sp36, 'sp37'=>$sp37, 'sp38'=>$sp38, 'sp39'=>$sp39, 'sp40'=>$sp40);
                DB::table('checklist_teachers')->insert($data1);
                echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";

                die("Form Submitted");
        }

    public function parents()
    {
        return view("parents");
    }

    public function submitparentform(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($request->input());
        $this->validate($request, [
            "cog1"=>"required",
            "cog2"=>"required",
            "cog3"=>"required",
            "cog4"=>"required",
            "cog5"=>"required",
            "cog6"=>"required",
            "cog7"=>"required",
            "cog8"=>"required",
            "cog9"=>"required",
            "cog10"=>"required",
            "cog11"=>"required",
            "cog12"=>"required",
            "cog13"=>"required",
            "cog14"=>"required",
            "cog15"=>"required",
            "cog16"=>"required",
            "phy17"=>"required",
            "phy18"=>"required",
            "phy19"=>"required",
            "phy20"=>"required",
            "phy21"=>"required",
            "phy22"=>"required",
            "phy23"=>"required",
            "phy24"=>"required",
            "phy25"=>"required",
            "se26"=>"required",
            "se27"=>"required",
            "se28"=>"required",
            "se29"=>"required",
            "se30"=>"required",
            "se31"=>"required",
            "se32"=>"required",
            "se33"=>"required",
            "se34"=>"required",
            "spt35"=>"required",
            "spt36"=>"required",
            "spt37"=>"required",
            "spt38"=>"required",
            "spt39"=>"required",
            "spt40"=>"required",
            ],[
                "cog1.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog2.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog3.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog4.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog5.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog6.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog7.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog8.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog9.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog10.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog11.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog12.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog13.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog14.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog15.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "cog16.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy17.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy18.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy19.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy20.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy21.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy22.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy23.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy24.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "phy25.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se26.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se27.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se28.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se29.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se30.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se31.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se32.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se33.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "se34.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "spt35.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "spt36.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "spt37.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "spt38.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "spt39.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
                "spt40.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",
            ]);

                //insert into database
            $user_id = Auth::user()->name;
            $cog1 = $request->input('cog1');
            $cog2 = $request->input('cog2');
            $cog3 = $request->input('cog3');
            $cog4 = $request->input('cog4');
            $cog5 = $request->input('cog5');
            $cog6 = $request->input('cog6');
            $cog7 = $request->input('cog7');
            $cog8 = $request->input('cog8');
            $cog9 = $request->input('cog9');
            $cog10 = $request->input('cog10');
            $cog11 = $request->input('cog11');
            $cog12 = $request->input('cog12');
            $cog13 = $request->input('cog13');
            $cog14 = $request->input('cog14');
            $cog15 = $request->input('cog15');
            $cog16 = $request->input('cog16');
            $phy17 = $request->input('phy17');
            $phy18 = $request->input('phy18');
            $phy19 = $request->input('phy19');
            $phy20 = $request->input('phy20');
            $phy21 = $request->input('phy21');
            $phy22 = $request->input('phy22');
            $phy23 = $request->input('phy23');
            $phy24 = $request->input('phy24');
            $phy25 = $request->input('phy25');
            $se26 = $request->input('se26');
            $se27 = $request->input('se27');
            $se28 = $request->input('se28');
            $se29 = $request->input('se29');
            $se30 = $request->input('se30');
            $se31 = $request->input('se31');
            $se32 = $request->input('se32');
            $se33 = $request->input('se33');
            $se34 = $request->input('se34');
            $spt35 = $request->input('spt35');
            $spt36 = $request->input('spt36');
            $spt37 = $request->input('spt37');
            $spt38 = $request->input('spt38');
            $spt39 = $request->input('spt39');
            $spt40 = $request->input('spt40');
            $data=array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'cog1'=>$cog1, 'cog2'=>$cog2, 'cog3'=>$cog3, 'cog4'=>$cog4, 'cog5'=>$cog5, 'cog6'=>$cog6, 'cog7'=>$cog7, 'cog8'=>$cog8, 'cog9'=>$cog9, 'cog10'=>$cog10, 'cog11'=>$cog11, 'cog12'=>$cog12, 'cog13'=>$cog13, 'cog14'=>$cog14, 'cog15'=>$cog15, 'cog16'=>$cog16, 'phy17'=>$phy17,  'phy18'=>$phy18, 'phy19'=>$phy19, 'phy20'=>$phy20, 'phy21'=>$phy21, 'phy22'=>$phy22, 'phy23'=>$phy23, 'phy24'=>$phy24, 'phy25'=>$phy25, 'se26'=>$se26, 'se27'=>$se27, 'se28'=>$se28, 'se29'=>$se29, 'se30'=>$se30, 'se31'=>$se31, 'se32'=>$se32, 'se33'=>$se33, 'se34'=>$se34, 'spt35'=>$spt35, 'spt36'=>$spt36, 'spt37'=>$spt37, 'spt38'=>$spt38, 'spt39'=>$spt39, 'spt40'=>$spt40);
            DB::table('checklist_parents')->insert($data);
            echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";

            die("Form Submitted");
        }
}
```

my web page where the form resides - most content in form was removed as it was too large to post

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <section>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="checklist-card-size">
        <div class="card" style="justify-content: center; align-items:center; width: 50%; margin: 10px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding: 5px;">Progress Bar</div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Teachers Checklist') }}</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" class="checklist-form" action="submit" multistep kw-cloak>
                    @csrf
                        <div class="kw-multistep-step">
                            <div class="form-section kw-multistep-body">
                                <div class="grid-container kw-multistep-body">
                                    <div><h4>Intellectual</h4></div>
                                    <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Disagree</label></div>
                                    <div class="grid-labels"><label>Disagree</label></div>
                                    <div class="grid-labels"><label>Neutral</label></div>
                                    <div class="grid-labels"><label>Agree</label></div>
                                    <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Agree</label></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="grid-container" style="background-color: AliceBlue;" id="int1" type="form-control">
                                    <div><label for="int1" class="grid-content-left">Has a sizeable vocabulary for age and peers.</label></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="int1"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="int1"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="int1"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="int1"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="int1"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="grid-container" id="int2" type="form-control">
                                    <div><label for="int2" class="grid-content-left">Reads and/or listens to texts at a higher level.</label></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="int2"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="int2"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="int2"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="int2"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="int2"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="grid-container" style="background-color: AliceBlue;" id="int3" type="form-control">
                                    <div><label for="int3" class="grid-content-left">School grade success with limited training/study.</label></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="int3"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="int3"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="int3"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="int3"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="int3"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="grid-container" id="int4" type="form-control">
                                    <div><label for="int4" class="grid-content-left">Outside school high achievement (with limited training/study).</label></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="int4"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="int4"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="int4"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="int4"></div>
                                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="int4"></div>
                                </div>

                            <div class="form-navigation">
                                <button type="button" class="previous btn btn-info float-left">Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" class="next btn btn-info float-right">Next</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess float-right">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>

@endsection
```

I've looked at so many sites for help and done the suggested edits but they haven't worked so far, I'm rather clueless on how to get my teachers route to be recognised. My parents form is formatted in a very similar way and it works fine, I wasn't sure if having 2 forms on sperate pages would be the cause, it doesn't seem too likely. The functions for these are in the same controller.

Comment: Is `Auth::routes()` twice a typo?

Comment: I am actually unaware of its full use, I assumed I needed it for the routes that need user authentication, works find for all my other pages that I have Auth::routes() for.

Comment: I think you only need to call it once. Out of curiousity, if you swap the parents and teachers code in the routes file, does it only submit the teachers form?

Comment: @verticallypicked I just realised, you are setting the route `submit` for the teachers form, then overriding the route `submit` with the parents form. You need both a `submit-teachers` and `submit-parents` route

Comment: Yeah the issue is that the `action` attribute on the form is set to submit on both forms, and in your routes you are overriding the `submit` route. What @brombeer said will work.

Comment: Both of your submit routes use the same URL (submit) but different methods, that's not gonna work. Make the urls unique, something like `'Route::post('/checklist-teachers/submit', ...` and `'Route::post('/checklist-parents/submit', ...`

Comment: How do I update my routes? I still dont see them in Route:list.
I changed my routes as @brombeer suggested, and should I change my actions too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you define routes with same endpoint(like `/submit`) in your route files, only the last is registered because endpoint must be unique & having multiple identical endpoints is not logical & can not exist(it's like you decide to use same address to point to different stores & homes in the city)! this is the case with your post routes. besides, you must start your endpoints with `/`

you defined two identical post routes to `/submit` which laravel registers the last one which points to `submitparentform()` method & that is why you don't see first post route which points to `submitteacherform()`

define your endpoints like `/submit/teacherform` & `/submit/parentform`

duplicate `Auth::routes();` is also unnecessary

**some extra tips for cleaner code** ;)

1. if all of your validation messages are equal (third parameter of `$this->validate()`), instead of repeating it many times, just write:
   `"*.required"=>"All questions must be filled in",`
   `*` means everything
2. when name of inputs match corresponding table fields in database, instead of sql query use eloquent & simply
   `ChecklistParent::create($request->all());`
   & of course `$request->all()` may need additional data or some exclusion, in your case it becomes:

`$request->merge(['user_id' => 1])->except(['_token'])`

eloquent makes working with database easy,
[read more about eloquent here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)

3. if all of your fields are required, instead of repeating name of all fields, you can [use this simple trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48058438/16991542) by [@okiemute-omuta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829645/okiemute-omuta) for validation.

& use die() & echo() only for testing purposes

hope it was resolving, best regards ;)

Answer (score 0):

since you are a beginner I suggest you to separate controllers

one for teacher and another one for parent then create the same method name submit for both controllers

except that i suggest to use specific FormRequest for validation

later it will be easier to handle with code

Auth:routes() are duplicated?