# How to validate at least one checkbox is checked in a loop in Laravel form?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-form

I have a collection of checkboxes in my application. What I want to do is validate whether at least one is checked and enable a submit button. Basically a front end validation. According to the current code, the user must select all the checkboxes. I know this should be a small issue but as I am new to Laravel framework it's a little bit confusing for me to understand. Please, someone, help me here.

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    <li>
        {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, null, ['class="role-li"', 'required']) }}
        {{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Normal validation should work for validating if at least one checkbox is check. Try with it by adding validation rule like 'roles' => 'required',

Comment: I have used this and validated it through the back end. But if the user didn't select a role it keeps submit button enabled and when submitting it displays the error message and not allowing to submit the data. I want to disable the button if the user didn't select any checkbox. I have required other Form fields and it is working fine. But here it expects the user to select all the checkboxes. I want to make it for at least one. How can I do that?

Comment: Want to require at least one checkbox as required other fields in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405524/how-to-set-form-input-required-attribute-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="testform" action="/comment" method="post" class="m-0 mt-4">
    @for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" class="role-li role{{$i}}" onclick='checktest()'> I have a bike<br>
    @endfor
</form>

<script>
        var minimumonechecked;
        var noofboxes = $('.role-li').length;
        function checktest(xyz) {
            minimumonechecked = false;
            for(i=0;i<noofboxes;i++){
                if ($('.role' + i).is(':checked')) {
                    minimumonechecked = true;
                }
            }
            console.log(minimumonechecked)
        };
</script>
```

this code works for me :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But bad luck it is not working.

Comment: can you check step by step and check where the code is wrong?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara-club-1\resources\views\users\user-create.blade.php) this is the error message. And the error is in {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, null, ['class="role-li role{{$key}}"', 'required']) }} this line of code.

Comment: 'class' => 'role-li role{{$key}}'     or   'class' => 'role-li , role{{$key}}'

one of this should work

Comment: okay, just check how can u give multiple classes to that checkbox, once that is sorted, try my script

Comment: check my answer, ive updated it, that code works perfectly for me :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I could solve the issue with your instructions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206434/discussion-between-akil-patel-and-anonymus).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```js
var checkboxes = $(".check-cls"),
    submitButt = $(".submit-btn");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>

<form>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" id="role-1" class="check-cls"> <label for="role-1">Role 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" id="role-2" class="check-cls"> <label for="role-2">Role 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" id="role-3" class="check-cls"> <label for="role-3">Role 3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" id="role-4" class="check-cls"> <label for="role-4">Role 4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" id="role-5" class="check-cls"> <label for="role-5">Role 5</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Submit" disabled>
    </div>
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinay_kaklotar/doLnbzcf/5/)